# meteorjs - from windows to ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, iron-router

I developed my meteorjs application on windows. Because of the problems with meteor on Windows, I uninstalled Windows and installed Ubuntu 13.10 to work on the project.

I copied the whole meteorjs application I made, and want to start it on my computer.

First problem! An error occured and it says that the mongoDB url is given wrong. So i created a new meteorjs app und copied my stuff in it (without the .meteor dir!) and now the mongo error is solved.

But now i have a another problem. It says

```
ReferenceError: Router is not defined
    at app/lib/router.js:20:1
```

I use the external package iron-router. after this error i tried the following:

- remove iron-router and add iron-router : same error
- deleted iron-router from my /packages, removed it, redownloaded and add iron-router: same error

I dont know whats the problem now. When i exec "add iron-router" there is no error. It says that the package was added. When i restart the server and/or reset the application the same error is shown.

Here are the line from app/lib/router.js

Line 20:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate : 'layoutDefault'
});
```

**Edit**
I solved the problem this way:

I created a new meteor app and then installed meteorite. Now attention:
On Ubuntu i got an Error that the command mrt cant be execute. To solve this you have to ype the following:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s nodejs node
```

Now i installed all packages i needed for my project. After this I copied all of my Files and folders insider my meteor app except /packages and /.meteor and paste these files and folders into my new app. Than i deleted the default app-stuff inside my new app.

Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `.meteor` directory contains some required files therefore the easiest for you would be to copy over the whole project directory to your linux box and then:

```
$ cd projectdir
$ meteor update
$ meteor reset
$ mrt install
$ meteor
```

The key here are:

- `meteor update` which updates meteor version
- `meteor reset` which deletes the database files
- `mrt install` which installs required packages from atmosphere

If you want a bare minimum file repo, you can delete the `local` directory from within `.meteor` and any third party packages from the `packages` directory

Once you run `mrt install` meteorite will install third party packages for you from scratch.

Also, meteor will look in `.meteor/packages` to see what your installed packages should be and  `.meteor/release` to see what version meteor is running. You might want to check the contents of these files.

After finishing up, I strongly suggest you sync your project to a remote source control repository like git or subversion (preferably git) so that you don't run into platform problems any more.

Comment: When i try to exec mrt install i get the error: "/usr/bin/env: node: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden". This means: "[...] node: File or Dir not found" I just installed meteorite via sudo npm -g install meteorite. The installation was successful. But than it seems not to work ...

Comment: The problem may be that you have use `sudo` to install. You should have used `sudo -H`.

Comment: "sudo -H mrt install" and "sudo mrt install" returned the same error as well

Comment: I was referring to your initial install of meteorite where you should have done `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`. You should now uninstall meteorite `sudo npm uninstall -g meteorite` or `sudo npm uninstall meteorite` whichever you have used at first, and then install again with the -H option

Comment: "sudo npm uninstall -g meteorite;sudo -H npm install -g meteorite" Same errors like before. I dont get it ...

Comment: problem fixed when exec the following: "cd /usr/bin; ln -s nodejs node"

Comment: hmm, how did you install node? if you have installed it using official repos, uninstall it and refer to https://chrislea.com/2013/03/15/upgrading-from-node-js-0-8-x-to-0-10-0-from-my-ppa/ for a new node version

Comment: I think my node version is fine, but the name was wrong. Node was in the package within meteor. But now the problem is solved by renaming it.

Comment: That is suspicious. It is not something that should happen ordinarily. I'd double check.